# Starting st from a vim keybind failes

Tags: bash, vim, latex, neovim, terminal-emulator

I am using vim as an editor for LaTeX and I use bib-files for my citations.
I want to write a function with which vim opens the currently used bib-file in a terminal which itself runs vim on the .bib-file and lets me edit it.

In the bash script I am using the line

`st -t bibfile_edit_terminal_floating -e nvim $BIBFILE_PATH &`

where `$BIBFILE_PATH` is the path of the file (which is correct and works).

When I run the line from a terminal, it opens a st as a separate process and in st opens the file in vim as I want it.
If I call the same line from vim / nvim as a command in a script, the command opens a terminal for a split second and then closes again.

I don't know what is going on.

If I use the line

`st -t bibfile_edit_terminal_floating -e nvim $BIBFILE_PATH` (without the ampersand at the ending), the file opens in a terminal like I want it but I cannot edit my original document as it waits for the process to finish, which is not what I want.

Please help!

Comment: Since you are already in Vim, why don't you simply do something like `:vsplit $BIBFILE_PATH`?

Comment: I thought of it, but the problem is, that there is a complex process behind finding the file and I need to execute a script for that. But should there be a way to execute vimsplit on the output of a bash file, I'd take it.

Comment: `:execute 'vsplit' system('foo')`

Comment: This worked, thank you very much. I needed to read the manual for the `:system` command as it is tricky to pass `%` as an argument but it worked in the end. Thank you very much.